# How do I check if item is already in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to add bookmarks to my humble blog using localStorage, but when I save the page on the array it keep saving the same entry over and over. I need a way to check if the page is already in the array and, if it is, not save it.

I've tried doing a check against null and 'undefined', but it doesn't appears to be solving anything.

```
<div id="bookmarkresults"> </div>

<script>
//We will be listening for the form to be sumbited
fetchBookmarks()

document.querySelector('.bookmark__this').addEventListener('click',saveBookmark);
//save bookmarks
function saveBookmark(e){

    console.log('works');
    //prevent from subitted
    var sitename = "site name";
    var sitedescription = "desc";
    var siteurl = "url";

    var bookmark = {
        name : sitename,
        description: sitedescription,
        url : siteurl
    }

    //test if bookmarks is null
    if(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null){
        //init array
        var bookmarks = [];
        //add to array
        bookmarks.push(bookmark);
        //set to Localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('bookmarks',JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === 'undefined') {
        console.log("already"); 

    } else {
        //get bookmarks from localstorage
        var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
        //add bookmark to array
        bookmarks.push(bookmark);
        //reset to Localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('bookmarks',JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    }
    //refetch bookmarks
    fetchBookmarks();
    e.preventDefault();
}
//delete bookmarks
function deleteBookmarks(url){
    //get bookmarks
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    //lopp
    for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length;i++){
        if(bookmarks[i].url == url){
            bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks',JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    //refetch bookmarks
    fetchBookmarks();

    document.getElementById(url).remove();
}

//fetch bookmarks 
function fetchBookmarks(){
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    //get output id
    var bookmarkresults = document.getElementById("bookmarkresults");
    //build output
    for(var i=0;i<bookmarks.length;i++){
        var name = bookmarks[i].name;
        var url = bookmarks[i].url;
        var description = bookmarks[i].description;
        bookmarkresults.innerHTML += '<div id="'+url+'" class="  col-md-2">'+
                                        '<h2>'+name+'</h2>'+
                                        '<p>'+
                                            '<a  href="'+url+'" role="button">'+name+'</a>'+
                                            '<br>'
                                            +description+
                                        '</p>'+
                                        '<p>'+
                                            '<a onClick="deleteBookmarks(\''+url+'\')" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">delete</a>'+
                                        '</p>'+
                                    '</div>';
    }
}



</script>
```

I am able to save the page on the localStorage and delete it from the array, but if I push the button it keeps saving the same page over and over.

I could turn the button off, once pressed, but that won't solve the issue if the user refreshes the page. I rather check if the page is in the array first, then, based on that, not save the data and turn off the button if I have to.

This is my fail attempt at checking what's in there and if its already stored. Keep in mind, this is a noob talking here.

```
//check if exists
function checkBookmarks(){
    //get bookmarks
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    //lopp
    for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length;i++){
        console.log(bookmarks[i]);
        if(bookmarks[i].url == url){
            bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else {
            console.log("repeated");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, okay, got it now, but the title suggests a very different question

Comment: `if(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null)` should be: `if(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` block you can just add a test to see if you already have the bookmark in local storage. Change this:

```
bookmarks.push(bookmark);
```

to:

```
if (!bookmarks.some(item => item.url === bookmark.url)) bookmarks.push(bookmark);
```

A second issue is that you never clear the HTML before *extending* it. So you actually never replace any bookmark on the display; you just keep appending what is in local storage to what was already on the screen.

So add this, in `fetchBookmarks`, before looping over the bookmarks:

```
  bookmarkresults.innerHTML = "";
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/850vjfop/)

Comment: Trincot, this appears to be the valid solution, but somehow it only works when I reload the browser. If I keep adding items, they keep appearing, but only vanish once I reload the browser. Is there a way to avoid them showing when I fetchBookmarks()?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle that demonstrates your issue? Your question's code does not contain the input form.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here is the fiddle trincot https://jsfiddle.net/u4rzg3hy/2/ 

My problem is that when I store a new bookmark, it gets automatically shown on the page (fetchBookmarks();), which is fine, but not when the bookmark was already stored. It should only show new bookmarks being stored, not the same bookmark over and over again.

The fiddle only has one bookmark, but when I add say, six or eight different pages to the bookmarks, every time I fetchBookmarks() I get a list of all those bookmarks stored printed on the page instead of that last one I'm actually storing right now.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer, thank you very much! ^___^

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === 'undefined'
```

This is no good and will not work - don't put quotes around the undefined keyword.

Instead of doing a laborious check against null and undefined, do this:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')) { ...
// will be true if the local storage does not contain that key, false if it does contain it
```

To delete the value for that key:

```
localStorage.removeItem('bookmarks')
```

If you use these [methods as described in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), you should manage easily.